# How to fix BootReciever java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
09-18 10:14:34.482: E/Trace(787): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 10:14:34.542: W/ResourceType(787): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
09-18 10:14:34.683: E/BootReceiver(787): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

can someone tell me how to fix this error,

**BroadcastReceiver java:**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
        try {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), MainActivity.tophone);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context); 
            wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
            wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(tempbitMap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainActivity.tophone` may be null. show full logcat

Comment: @SilentKiller I added my logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application is unable to find `MainActivity.tophone` as your device is booted just and your application is yet no open it mean `tophone` variable is yet initialized. So it is firing `NullPointerException` because of `No package identifier` it mean it is unable to find resource with a given name which actually is null.

Resolve :

- Declare value of tophone it self in Broadcast
- Store Value in SharedPreference in activity and fetch it in BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer, but how do I store the value in the SharedPreference?